# Two similar codes but one does not work (Bokeh for Python)

Tags: python, plot, bokeh

I have two different but similar codes in python that use Bokeh to make an interactive plot. The following code works fine (I found it online).

```
import numpy as np

from bokeh.layouts import column, row
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, CustomJS, Slider
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 500)
y = np.sin(x)

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, y=y))

plot = figure(y_range=(-10, 10), width=400, height=400)

plot.line('x', 'y', source=source, line_width=3, line_alpha=0.6)

amp = Slider(start=0.1, end=10, value=1, step=.1, title="Amplitude")
freq = Slider(start=0.1, end=10, value=1, step=.1, title="Frequency")
phase = Slider(start=-6.4, end=6.4, value=0, step=.1, title="Phase")
offset = Slider(start=-9, end=9, value=0, step=.1, title="Offset")

callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source, amp=amp, freq=freq, phase=phase, offset=offset),
                    code="""
    const A = amp.value
    const k = freq.value
    const phi = phase.value
    const B = offset.value

    const x = source.data.x
    const y = Array.from(x, (x) => B + A*Math.sin(k*x+phi))
    source.data = { x, y }
""")

amp.js_on_change('value', callback)
freq.js_on_change('value', callback)
phase.js_on_change('value', callback)
offset.js_on_change('value', callback)

show(row(plot, column(amp, freq, phase, offset)))
```

However the next one does produce a plot but the sliders do not respond.

```
import numpy as np

from bokeh.layouts import column, row
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, CustomJS, Slider
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 500)
y = np.sin(x)

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, y=y))

plot = figure(y_range=(-10, 10), width=400, height=400)

plot.line('x', 'y', source=source, line_width=3, line_alpha=0.6)

amp1 = Slider(start=0, end=10, value=1, step=.1, title="Amplitude 1")
amp2 = Slider(start=0, end=10, value=0, step=.1, title="Amplitude 2")
freq1 = Slider(start=0, end=10, value=1, step=.1, title="Frequency 1")
freq2 = Slider(start=0, end=10, value=0, step=.1, title="Frequency 2")
phase1 = Slider(start=-6.4, end=6.4, value=0, step=.1, title="Phase 1")
phase2 = Slider(start=-6.4, end=6.4, value=0, step=.1, title="Phase 2")
offset1 = Slider(start=-9, end=9, value=0, step=.1, title="Offset 1")
offset2 = Slider(start=-9, end=9, value=0, step=.1, title="Offset 2")

callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source, amp1=amp1, freq1=freq1, phase1=phase1, offset1=offset1, amp2=amp2, freq2=freq2, phase2=phase2, offset2=offset2),
                    code="""
    const A = amp1.value
    const AA = amp2.value
    const f = freq1.value
    const ff = freq2.value
    const phi = phase1.value
    const phiphi = phase2.value
    const B = offset1.value
    const BB = offset3.value

    const x = source.data.x
    const y = Array.from(x, (x) => A*Math.sin(f*x+phi)+AA*Math.sin(ff*x+phiphi)+B+BB)
    source.data = { x, y }
""")

amp1.js_on_change('value', callback)
freq1.js_on_change('value', callback)
phase1.js_on_change('value', callback)
offset1.js_on_change('value', callback)
amp2.js_on_change('value', callback)
freq2.js_on_change('value', callback)
phase2.js_on_change('value', callback)
offset2.js_on_change('value', callback)

show(row(plot, column(amp1, freq1, phase1, offset1, amp2, freq2, phase2, offset2)))
```

The second plotted function is a bit more complicated but it should work. Why does it not work?

There is not really anything I could try other than checking my code for typos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the second code change

```
const BB = offset3.value
```

to

```
const BB = offset2.value
```